# Conditionally define a const in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search page, which queries an api to get an array of objects. It then renders a  for each element of the array. I'm trying to achieve this like so:

```
export default class SearchScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl =
      "foo";
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response =>
        this.setState({
          results: response.results
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
      {this.state.results ? (
          const items = this.state.results.map((item, index) => {
               return (
                    <div>
                        <SearchResult name={item.name} />
                    </div>
                    );
       })
        return <div>{items}</div>;
       ) : (<div> LOADING...</div>)}
}
```

So, if this.state.results is not null, it should map its contents to a const, and then generate SearchResult elements.

It is complaining that `const` is an unexpected keyword. Is there something wrong with conditionally defining constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statements (like `const items = [];`) cannot be used with the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). You can only use expressions. If you want to write a full statement, you have to use `if`.

You can change the logic a bit to accomplish what you want with the ternary operator though:

```
return this.state.results ? (
    <div>
      {this.state.results.map((item, index) => (
        <div>
          <SearchResult name={item.name} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ) :
  (
    <div> LOADING...</div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect, below is fixed one:

```
render() {
      const items = this.state.results ? (
          this.state.results.map((item, index) => {
              return ( 
                  // Use better key
                    <div key={index}><SearchResult name={item.name} /></div>
              );
          }
        )) : 'LOADING...';

        return <div>{items}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix like this:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.results
          ? this.state.results.map((item, index) => <SearchResult name={item.name} />)
          : 'LOADING...'}
      </div>
    );
  }
```